# Passing objects between timers and post ajax requests (anonymous functions)

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, settimeout, anonymous-function

I have struggled on this topic for a quite a bit of time and it just won't click!

I need to pass the object to the `&.post` (WordPress processed AJAX) request, but I cannot figure out how to do it correctly using regular variables; instead, I'm forced to call $(document) and iterate over it's DOM elements (very ugly and slow).

How would I correct this code so I'm able to pass the title variable all the way to the post data, instead using `$(document).find('#sections_title').val() request`?

Please explain how to do this properly.

```
(function ($) {
    var title = $('#sections_title');
    var timeout = 2000;

    var delay = (function () {
        var timer = 0;

        return function (callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

    title.keyup(function () {

        // i would like to have variable here, that grabs the $(this).val()
        // and use this variable to pass to the data
        // var value = .......

        delay(function () {
            $.post(
                ajaxurl,
                {
                    'action': 'add_foobar',
                    'data': $(document).find('#sections_title').val()
                    // instead I would like:
                    // 'data': value
                },
                function(response){
                    alert('The server responded: ' + response);
                }
            );

        }, timeout);
    })();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easiest way for your case.
Bind the val as object to callback. Then cast this to string when you need to use it.

```
    delay(function () {
        $.post(
            ajaxurl,
            {
                'action': 'add_foobar',
                'data': String(this)
                // instead I would like:
                // 'data': value
            },
            function(response){
                alert('The server responded: ' + response);
            }
        );

    }.bind(Object($(this).val())), timeout);
```

Or here is the complete code

```
(function ($) {
    var title = $('#sections_title');
    var timeout = 2000;

    var delay = (function () {
        var timer = 0;

        return function (callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

    title.keyup(function () {

        // i would like to have variable here, that grabs the $(this).val()
        // and use this variable to pass to the data
        // var value = .......

        delay(function () {
            $.post(
                ajaxurl,
                {
                    'action': 'add_foobar',
                    'data': String(this)
                    // instead I would like:
                    // 'data': value
                },
                function(response){
                    alert('The server responded: ' + response);
                }
            );

        }.bind(Object($(this).val())), timeout);
    })();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is what I used. But I have one question, why di you convert text to the object? I passed 'this' in the bind, and extracted entire jquery object from within the delay function.

Comment: @HelpNeeder That will work too, But since I need only value, I did not want to create a reference for element or jquery object. I converted value to Object because I did not want to have String prototype members on this  object. Just for boxing

Comment: Ah! Well i did state I needed only value. I do appreciate other ways of passing values too, though. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can set it explicitly on the [window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp). In the browser, the global object is the same as the window object, except for certain environments like `node.js`.

```
(function($) {
    window.title = $('#sections_title');
    var timeout = 2000;

    var delay = (function() {
        var timer = 0;

        return function(callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

    title.keyup(function() {    
        delay(function() {
            $.post(
                ajaxurl, {
                    'action': 'add_foobar',
                    'data':  window.title
                },
                function(response) {
                    alert('The server responded: ' + response);
                }
            );

        }, timeout);
    })();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I wouldn't use this as it could create a conflict with other JS codes. But I do like the idea. Thanks!